# Has the west debated the pros and cons of funding Ukraine war aid with the Russian funds they have confisticated?

Tags: ukraine, europe, foreign-aid, g7

With Ukrainian aid funds blocked in the U.S. Congress / Senate and other western countries struggling to financially pick up the U.S. share of this burden, talks are getting more serious in Europe and the United States to set aside $300 billion of Russian funds, a portion frozen in Western Banks, and use that to fund Ukrainian military aid.

- **[U.S. and Europe Eye Russian Assets to Aid Ukraine as Funding Dries Up.](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/12/21/us/politics/russian-assets-ukraine.html)**
- **[G7 moves closer to seizing Russian assets for Ukraine](https://www.ft.com/content/918645f8-e0b6-4cab-92fa-4f965569c2a6)**
- **[Daleep Singh](https://www.axios.com/2023/08/03/russian-central-bank-assets-seized-ukraine)**, a former top Biden administration official, suggested that the funds should be placed in an escrow account that Ukraine could have access to and be used as collateral for Ukrainian government bonds.
- Others have argued that countries that hold Russian assets can legally cancel their obligations to Russia and use those assets to pay for what Russia owes for its breach of international law.

**Question:**
Have NATO / EU politicians discussed what are the pros and cons of spending the Russian frozen funds and how it can be done? (I am not asking for personal opinions but verifiable statements).

One consequence was given on 22 December, 2023 by Russia's Deputy Foreign Minister Ryabkov:

**[Moscow could sever diplomatic relations with the United States should it confiscate Russian assets frozen under sanctions, Deputy Foreign Minister Sergey Ryabkov said on Friday.](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/12/22/russia-may-sever-ties-respond-in-kind-over-seizure-of-its-assets)**

Comment: Important note missed by both sides of the debate: spending Russian reserves in the U.S. is effectively a net loss for the American economy regardless of who the beneficiary is. As long as the funds are parked in America they’re a part of the U.S. economy - moving them out would thus hurt the US economy.

Comment: @JonathanReez,  Unless you confiscate them and then spend them in the U.S. to pay for that military aid.   Although I think you are right.  I believe they are discussing sending the funds to Ukraine to fund the government or reconstruction after the war.

Answer (score 12):

Former US Ambassador to Russia Michael McFaul argues for such transfer, for two reasons:

- Paying reparations for a violation of international law is a well-established norm.
- It would be immoral to give these funds back to Russia.
- It is immoral to ask American (or European) taxpayers to pay for Ukrainian budget support or eventual reconstruction and not to ask Russians to do the same.

By contrast, the US Treasury secretary Janet Yellen said in 2022 that:

- The seizure was “not something that is legally permissible in the United States” without an act of Congress.

---

**References:**

> Given recent Congressional debates on continuing U.S. aid to Ukraine, The Washington Post published an op-ed, discerning whether we should use seized assets of the Central Bank of Russia to pay for the war in Ukraine. I vote yes and believe that Congress should (1) approve new U.S. funds for Ukraine (the subject of this piece in Foreign Policy), and (2) pass the Rebuilding Economic Prosperity and Opportunity (REPO) for Ukrainians Act, which would transfer sovereign assets of the Russian Federation currently frozen in Western financial institutions to Ukraine. While the sum confiscated by the United States is just a fraction of the total currently frozen by the West, U.S. leadership will make it easier for Europeans to follow suit. Others disagree, making the case that doing so violates international law.
>
> Read both viewpoints here: https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2023/11/16/russia-ukraine-assets-seizure-sovereign-immunity/

*[Should We Seize Russian Funds to Pay for the War in Ukraine?](https://michaelmcfaul.substack.com/p/should-we-seize-russian-funds-to)*

---

> But the gist is as follows: paying reparations for a violation of international law is a well-established norm. And seizing assets of the Russian Central Bank and transferring them to Ukraine is the only realistic and feasible proposal, currently on the table, for how to force Russia to comply with paying reparations. Remember, Russia is one of the five permanent members of the UN Security Council (which, by the way, Russia currently chairs), hence they can always veto any proposals about reparations in that body. Additionally, as we write in the paper, “only clear-cut losers in wars pay reparations.” Two things here: (1) Russia has nuclear weapons and, therefore, as some argue, “cannot be defeated militarily,” and (2) Putin is an autocrat, who will bend the narrative however he wants, whenever it is convenient. For that matter, he might declare that Russia has completed its “special military operation,” and achieved all its military objectives in Ukraine tomorrow, or in a month's time. What is clear, is that Putin will not accept the international community’s verdict that Russia has lost and therefore will never pay reparations.
>
> Moreover, it would be immoral to give these funds back to Russia. First, Putin violated some of the most central norms of the UN Charter when his army invaded Ukraine both in 2014 and 2022, annexed Ukrainian territory again both in 2014 and 2022, and then committed crimes against humanity against Ukrainian citizens. $300 billion is just one down payment on what Russia must eventually pay for these crimes. Second, Russia’s full-scale invasion of Ukraine, produced a spike in global oil and gas prices, meaning that Russia, a major exporter of oil and gas, profited from starting this war. These windfall profits were well above the value of the seized assets of the Central Bank of Russia. Third, it is immoral to ask American (or European) taxpayers to pay for Ukrainian budget support or eventual reconstruction and not to ask Russians to do the same. In fact, I think it would be political suicide for President Biden to agree to give Russia these billions back while asking Americans for billions more to help Ukraine’s case. This is just simply unfair.

*[Transfer the Seized Assets of the Russian Central Bank to Ukraine Now!](https://michaelmcfaul.substack.com/p/transfer-the-seized-assets-of-the)*

---

> The Ukrainian government had previously called on its supporters in the west to seize Russian assets to create a reconstruction fund for Ukraine, but the Biden administration has demurred, with [the US Treasury secretary Janet Yellen] saying in 2022 that the seizure was “not something that is legally permissible in the United States” without an act of Congress.

*[Russia warns US and Europe over reports Ukraine may get its seized assets | Russia | The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/dec/22/russia-europe-us-ukraine-seized-assets)*

Comment: "Paying reparations for a violation of international law is a well-established norm." <- Funny statement coming from a US official, but not false as such...

Comment: @einpoklum I am missing the joke here, sorry.

Comment: Paying reparations requires having a peace treaty first and is done to avoid continuing the war. Nobody pays reparations with explicit intent to give their opponent in a hot war more means to continue it. So it is disingenous to call such wealth transfer reparations, much like calling somebody pouring gasoline into the fire a firefighter

Comment: @TimurShtatland: The US routinely disregards international law and has recently been making up its own "rules-based order"; and it is definitely not in the habit of paying other states reparations for its violations.

Comment: @einpoklum On the whole, the US is more helpful than harmful to the rules-based world order. To give just a few recent examples, there are the US actions against: Russian aggression and threats since 2014 & especially since 2022; China w.r.t. its threats against Taiwan; Taliban violations of human rights in Afghanistan; North Korean threats against South Korea and Japan; Iran's support of terrorism abroad and violation of human rights; etc. Yes, one can say that there were also the wars in Iraq, Vietnam, etc. But **the pros of the US policies far outweigh the cons**.

Comment: @TimurShtatland: The problem _is_ the US' "rules-based world order". And your examples certainly show how it just boils down to the pursuit of its imperial interests.

Comment: @einpoklum Ukraine (both the government & the population) is opposed to Russian aggression & threats. So are the Baltic states, Poland, Moldova, Georgia, etc. Afghan women are opposed to Taliban-enforced restrictions on them. S. Korea is opposed to N. Korean threats. The rest of my examples also show that it is the **others** that are asking for the Western help in enforcing the rules-based order. The US has its own interests, true (for example, weakening its adversaries). But to say that the US help *"just boils down to the pursuit of its imperial interests"* simply contradicts the evidence.

Comment: Yes, yes, i remember when the US run from Afghanistan, thay said for the bye: why are you, Taliban, destroying the opium fields that we grew for your nation so hard, that is a decent business, why you are destroying it, you economic is suffering dmg... This help was gifted by the order-lords, and also military stuff for 85 billions. Best help for 20 years ruling... it reminds crocodile tears of brits in second opium war in China. Nothing had changed, an old story.

Comment: The problem, that when you are inventing "new" narrations, history is saying definitely contrary to your invented story. In Russia  we say for such cases: никогда такого не было и вот опять - that was never happened but it was again.

Comment: @άνθρωπος Yes, of course, Russian-area folks have many, many, lessons to give to the rest of the world in how to handle Afghanistan.  Plus, your claims don't make all that much sense either:  NATO invested quite a lot of effort and $$$ to get rid of the poppy fields.  Now, it didn't actually work all that well, pissed-off poppy farmers often joined the Taliban and payments for not growing poppies often failed to reach their goal.  But this claim: *we grew for your nation so hard, that is a decent business, why you are destroying it* makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @einpoklum It may not make all that much sense from a non-Western perspective, but for many, far from all, Westerners, the USA achieved several things in the last 80 years:  removing Nazis (w lots of help from the USSR) and avoiding a world takeover by Soviet Communism, a system explicitly geared towards world takeover.  Now, if you want to figure out why that matters to us, read up some Solzhenitsyn, check out the history of the Khmer Rouge, the Great Leap Forward, Katyn massacre, Hungary 56, Czechoslovakia 68, mine fields to keep people **in** Soviet countries...  Lots of stuff to ponder.

Comment: @Italian Philosophers 4 Monica Solzhenitsyn is not ever honest documental historical reading, his numbers is 100 times more then any official, he wasn't ever in Siberia's or another hard-prison-camps, which about he rote his fiction texts. About opium - it is easy numbers and statistic, that start in 1979 when the US came in this region with help, and that was continue to grow up after SU-US Afghan conflict, and after 2003(the US in Afghanistan official and alone) it grew to top 1 leading of the opium, heroin and late methamphetamine producing - all is under the US ruling.

Comment: @άνθρωπος Solzhenitsyn is so bogus that he discredited Soviet Communism throughout the Western European intellectuals, so I find your claims extremely unconvincing.  [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulag) : *The emergent consensus among scholars is that, of the 14 million prisoners who passed through the Gulag camps and the 4 million prisoners who passed through the Gulag colonies from 1930 to 1953, roughly 1.5 to 1.7 million prisoners perished there or they died soon after they were released.*  So, you telling me Solz claimed, @ 100x,  150million deaths?

Comment: @Italian Philosophers 4 Monica "По его(Курганова) подсчётам, мы потеряли во Второй мировой войне от пренебрежительного, от неряшливого её ведения 44 миллиона человек! Итак, всего мы потеряли от социалистического строя — 110 миллионов человек! Поразительно, что Достоевский в конце прошлого века предсказал, что социализм обойдётся России в сто миллионов человек. . Достоевский это сказал в 70-х годах Девятнадцатого века. В это нельзя было поверить. Фантастическая цифра! Но она не только сбылась, она превзойдена: мы потеряли сто десять миллионов и продолжаем терять." Solzhenitsin 20.03.1976 Spain

Comment: "It may not make all that much sense from a non-Western perspective" <- Doesn't make sense from a Western perspective, if it's not the perspective of the ruling class. And "the US is better than the worst genocidal governments of the 20th century" is a very weak argument, especially coming from someone who is spurring US senators to support the Israeli campaign in Gaza right now.

Comment: Stalinist communism was not geared towards world domination anymore.

Comment: @TimurShtatland Even with the war in Iraq, it was because Iraq refused to abide by the cease fire that it had agreed to in the aftermath of it invading Kuwait. And with Vietnam, the US' desired outcome was closer to the status quo than the Viet Cong's was.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**. A good overview article [here](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/12/21/us/politics/russian-assets-ukraine.html?unlocked_article_code=1.Hk0.dprf.g_nvWQ0R8HFU&smid=nytcore-android-share) from the New York Times. They have debated and are still doing so. That much is no doubt.

> The Biden administration is quietly signaling new support for seizing more than $300 billion in Russian central bank assets stashed in Western nations and has begun urgent discussions with allies about using the funds to aid Ukraine’s war effort at a moment when financial support is waning.

And, from the Russian side, as [cited](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/dec/22/russia-europe-us-ukraine-seized-assets?CMP=Share_AndroidApp_Other) by The Guardian:

> The illegitimate seizure of our assets **invariably remains on the agenda** both in Europe and America

So remains. Russia even threatens to deploy short and medium-range missiles in Europe or the Asia-Pacific region in response to this financial action.

The main argument against seems banks do not want to lose the reputation of being safe place to keep this money, and lots of attention to respect the property. Dollars and euro may lose reputation, preferring other currencies, even if these are not without they own problems. Due these reasons the early discussions ended more or less with conclusion "maybe better not now".

But as "collective west" seems running out of money to support Ukraine, the discussions are rising again. These assets are much more than Ukraine ever received.

Under the more recent plans as proposed by Belgian government, Kyiv could raise debt rather than using these money directly. The coalition supporting Ukraine would demand that Russia repays the debt and, if it does not, would seize frozen Russian assets instead ([Financial Times](https://on.ft.com/4boTqfd), C.Cook, H.Foy, L.Dubois). The same source says there are talks about using at least interest rates for the Ukraine support. These alone amount to 4,4 billion per year or about.

This is now cooling down because EU help has passed, and US help has improved prospects to pass, so it is less critical.

**Update**: Britain is 'prepared to loan Ukraine all frozen Russian central bank assets in UK' ([The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2024/mar/06/russia-ukraine-war-live-emmanuel-macron-urges-ukraines-allies-not-to-be-cowards)).

Answer (score -1):

One more negative aspect missed by the other answers:

#### Transferring Russian reserves to Ukraine is a net loss for Western economies

Russian assets are mostly invested into bonds or simply deposited into bank accounts in the U.S. or the EU. This means that they’re effectively a part of the Western financial system and help support Western economies. If the West chooses to spend these assets to help Ukraine, this would still represent a net loss for the West either in the form of increased inflation or by harming the supply of capital available to Western businesses.

This would still be a net loss for the West if the funds were unfrozen and Russia moved them out into other countries. Thus the most profitable solution is to keep them frozen for as long as possible. You can certainly argue that saving Ukraine is more important than propping up the economy but the decision makers still have to contend with the fact that *any* transfer of resources is effectively a drain on their own taxpayers.

Comment: I'm actually not sure it is so, from the economics standpoint. Any USD that US have moved out of country act as its debit for which it purchases services and goods (in this case for shipping to Ukraine, but they might as well send used stuff and buy new stuff for themselves). Any USDs they have inside the country are just numbers in a spreadsheet.

Comment: @alamar,  It does depend on how you spend the funds.  Jonathan is correct if the Russian funds are given to Ukraine to pay for government operations or reconstruction which I believe is on the table.   You are more correct if the Russian funds pay for U.S. weapons.  I still think Johnathan is correct though, because it's not like the new stuff doesn't cost several times what the old stuff would cost.   An F16 cost 8 million $ in 1980.  Today's modern equivalent would be the F-35 is 10 times that number.   That's true roughly for all the old weapon systems going to Ukraine.

Comment: @alamar,   All in $300 billion has been frozen across world.   Some fraction of that in the US.   Let's say the US has $100 billion and spends it all in 2024 an election year.    That's still only  .4% of the US 23 trillion dollar gdp.   So while that would certainly help me with my bills,  it's not going to hurt or help the US economy much.   I would also say it's likely for Russia to retaliate and freeze and confiscate US/NATO assets in their control.

Comment: @JMS by that logic you might as well spend $300 billion from the budget because it's supposed to be chump change. But those "chump changes" tend to add up and cause inflation, which voters in the US absolutely loathe.